# Citing a text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just getting started in programming and somehow can't come up with any sensible approach to the following problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated! I have a .html file structured like this:

```
<head>
<title>ABC</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="norm">
...    
<span class="jnenbez">13</span>
....    
<div class="Absatz">text</div>
<div class="Absatz">text</div>
<div class="Absatz">CITE HERE**</div>
```

The "norm" div is the one parent node. The "jnenbez" span and the "Absatz" divs are inside the "norm" div, but how deeply they are nested can vary. Now I want to cite the "CITE HERE" area, meaning to generate the output of **"jnenbez 13 Absatz 3 ABC"** - meaning getting the text content of the "jnenbez" span of the same "norm" div, getting the index number of the "Absatz" div, since it is the third child "Absatz" of the "norm" div and getting the  content.

1) How could I give this string to the user, so he could copy paste it somewhere else? It seems it is not easily possible to modify the copy+paste behavior of Firefox. An obvious solution would be to put the output in brackets like [jnenbez...] at the end of each divs text content, but that would reduce readability of the html...

2) Is it even possible to automatically generate this output via JQuery?

Comment: You can't control the system clipboard with javascript. You might be able to implement a small flash plugin that automatically changes the content of the system clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about a good way to store/display the info.
Also, unsure of what other mark-up you would have in the class='norm' container. This is vitally important and impacts entirely the shape of the useful solution.

I've assumed a particular structure - one that says the first contained span is one of interest. Another assumption is that the only divs in the container are of interest and need to be counted.

I'm sure you can break it easily enough. :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onBtnPress(element)
{
    var result;

    var cont = element.parentNode;

    var span = cont.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    result = span.className + " ";
    result += span.innerHTML + " ";

    var divList = cont.getElementsByTagName('div');
    result += divList[0].className + " ";
    result += divList.length+" ";
    result += document.title;

    cont.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

<title>ABC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="norm">
        <span class="jnenbez">13</span>
        <div class="Absatz">text</div>
        <div class="Absatz">text</div>
        <div class="Absatz">CITE HERE**</div>
        <button onclick='onBtnPress(this);'>click me</button>
        <p>[string here]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="norm">
        <span class="Crapple">8</span>
        <div class="ipod">worst</div>
        <div class="ipod">music</div>
        <div class="ipod">player</div>
        <div class="ipod">I ever</div>
        <div class="ipod">bought</div>
        <div class="ipod">CITE HERE**</div>
        <button onclick='onBtnPress(this);'>click me</button>
        <p>[string here]</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```